# Figure out non standard ssh port

Tags: ssh, port

I have this server that is configured to use another port instead of 22 for ssh. How may I figure out which port number it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you don't have access to command line (otherwise you would already know what the port number was), you can do a port scan to try and identify which port the SSH service is running on.  I would suggest running nmap.  There's no guarantee though that it will find it.

Comment: I try to scan using this command `nmap -p 8000-8999 -r domain.com` because I just remember it start with 8 for 4 digit. Is that enough to tell nmap I want to search for ssh? If the ssh is on 8111 did it will relize the opened port is ssh? I can't get it work because my IP already blocked by my server. I install something to prevent brute force. Now I am searching nmap command switch to scan slowly.

Answer (score 32):

Run `nmap -sV <hostname/ip>` - which is nmap with service detection, meaning it works out what's actually listening on the port, rather than guessing the service based on the port it's using.

This will give you output that looks something like:

`PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION`

`666/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 5.3p1 Debian 3ubuntu4 (protocol 2.0)`

If it still doesn't find the port, run `nmap -p- -sV <hostname/IP>` - this will scan all 65k ports - it's slower, but it will find it if it's running on a high up port.

Answer (score 31):

If you have access to the commandline, and read access to */etc/ssh/sshd_config*, run

```
grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Wow!! This is exactly what I was looking for.. :)

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Both answers here (nmap and grep on the config file) are nice.
Although, for completion - if you do have access to the said "command line", I would use this:

```
ss -ltp
```

This should give you all the listening ports (with their respective app names)
(Sometimes you might have a custom dropbear for ssh - or just another custom solution that doesn't necessarily use /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
Have fun "linuxing" away relentlessly! :)

Eventually, you can use `grep` to filter your wanted info:

```
ss -ltp | grep ssh
```

Although you need to know that openssh is not the only application that provides the ssh service (I actually use the complementary `mosh` app for some functionality that I consider better than the ssh :) ...)